# how to copy Word Document contents to Google Docs using any command line tool or Scripts

Tags: javascript, ms-word, google-drive-api

I have a word doc in my local drive and I want to copy the whole content of the word doc to any specific google docs file using any Command line tool or script

Please let me know if you have any clarifications I will explain my requirements further

Thanks
Vimal

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) or [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads).

> In Apps Script advanced Drive service allows you to use the Google Drive web API in Apps Script. Much like Apps Script's built-in Drive service, this API allows scripts to create, find, and modify files and folders in Google Drive.

The following example demonstrates how to save a file to a user's Drive.

```
function uploadFile() {
var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch('DOCUMENT_EXPORT_URL').getBlob();
var file = {
title: 'google_logo.png',
mimeType: 'image/png'
};
file = Drive.Files.insert(file, image);
Logger.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', file.id, file.fileSize);
}
```

Following this sample code, you will get the blob for the file and save it as the converted file.

This is a tutorial for [converting documents](https://ctrlq.org/code/20009-convert-google-documents)(excel to spreadsheet)

---

I haven't tested this but for the Drive Rest API try using `downloadURL` to get the file in order to upload it as Google Format by setting the property `convert=true` (making a copy of it in google docs) or getting the blob saving it as Google docs.

Snippet for uploading file: setting the contentType.

```
var fileName = 'convertedFile';
var contentType = 'application/vnd.google-aps.document';
var metadata = {
'title': fileName,
'mimeType': contentType
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr.Rebot, but I am new to  Apps Script and Drive REST API, so Can you tell me whether I can use this scripts to run as a command line tool or any other script from my computer locally ??